# Accessing Properties of the code-behind from aspx page in web application project

Tags: asp.net, web-applications, properties, namespaces

I have a property **x** in my code-behind file in a web application project. It gives me compile time error while it does not give any error in website project

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebForm1.aspx.cs" 
Inherits="test.WebForm1" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>
<%= x2 %>
<%# x2 %>
</div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Codebehind file :

```
using System;
namespace test
{public partial class WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    public int x2 = 2;
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {          
    }     
   }
}
```

It is working fine when I use the same technique in my website project 
Kindly help 
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if there are any other errors in your code behind **WebForm1.aspx.cs.**
like missing reference or any other compile error.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me. Are you sure there's a value in ViewState? On form load add a value to test.

```
ViewState["FormMode"] = "ViewApplicant";
lblMessage.DataBind();
```

Also make sure the label has some text to view. It could be showing but is empty.

```
<asp:Label ID="lblMessage" runat="server" 
    Text="some text" 
    Visible='<%# FormMode == "View" || FormMode == "ViewApplicant" %>'>
</asp:Label>
```

Comment: The problem is not with the Viewstate. Any other property is also not accessible. it is giving compile time error. The Name 'FormMode' does not exist in the current context

Answer (score 0):

Your code is perfectly okay. While accessing the variable/property initillay, the red underline may appear under the expression indicating the compile error, but when you build the solution, there should be no error.

Answer (score 0):

Your original post has changed so here's a new answer.

Try removing the namespace from the code behind and change 'inherits' on the page to `Inherits="WebForm1"`.

page directive:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebForm1.aspx.cs"
    Inherits="WebForm1" %>
```

code behind:

```
using System;

public partial class WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    public int x2 = 2;
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    }     
}
```

'Inherits' must match the partial class name.